# A Reliable UDP Implementation

Tags: c++, udp, network-protocols

I need an implementation of UDP that meets the following criteria:

- Available on Linux and Mac (only latest versions matter)
- Usable from C++
- Orders packets
- Guaranties packet delivery
- Non conection oriented (like UDP)

NOTE: I do NOT want to use TCP for this.
NOTE: It can be implemented by any socket API, as long as it is available on the two platforms and is available to C++.

EDIT:
I have looked at the UDT, RUDP, and SCTP. These seem to be the major contenders. Any thoughts?

EDIT:
[UDT](http://udt.sourceforge.net/) seems to be what I am looking for. Is the fact that it is implemented in user-space over the kernels UDP going to be a huge performance problem? Or will the speeds still be faster than TCP/STCP?

EDIT (2/15/12):
I have came up with a solution that uses TCP and a central redirection server. The system lets one client send data to the server through an ever-open TCP connection, who them gives it along to the right other client along the server's TCP connection to the second.

Comment: If you want to do everything TCP does, and lose all the reasons for using UDP, then you should probably give a good reason for not using TCP if you want to get good/useful answers.

Comment: If you want ordered, guaranteed packet delivery, doesn't that *make* it stream oriented?

Comment: Maybe because UDP is connection-less?

Comment: @todda.speot.is: That's what I meant. I made an edit.

Comment: It makes sense if you're using a publish-subscribe system.

Comment: That's not "an implementation *of* UDP", that's a session protocol implemented on top of UDP.

Comment: And it won't be connectionless anymore, since you have to keep track of which recipients haven't yet received which particular packets.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson: I want a protocol that does not require opening a connection, but that rather uses the same one-shot approach of UDP.

Comment: @BenVoigt's comment is the key. Even if you use something like UDP to send the packets, both sender and receiver now need to maintain state in order to achieve reliability. That state is basically a connection.

Comment: The question seems to be inconsistent. First OP says that he wants _Non conection oriented (like UDP)_, then SCTP is chosen as one of contenders... But SCTP uses an association which effectively is connection. I think OP should elaborate more on that point.

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh What will happen is you will end up manually handling the same kind of transaction/connection level details at software level, rather than relying on tried-and-true implementations at the kernel (or even hardware?) level.

Comment: @PavelZhuravlev I suggested it because it's message-based, like UDP. As you know, you can't provide stateless reliable message delivery - "this message was sent" is a bit of state, and you need to keep that. So I assumed "no connections" actually meant "message based".

Comment: @Borealid: That was a correct assumption, but I need a system that does not involve expensive connections. If the interior implementation uses some sort of state, that is fine. I want to be able to 'fire and forget', to put it that way.

Comment: @PavelZhuravlev: I did not say that SCTP would work. It is just one of the answers.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but I saw that nobody answered anything about UDT. I have some experience with it, so I can share them.

UDT works pretty good. You basically use it like you would an UDP socket, and get all the thing that you listed from it.

Performance-wise, I haven't noticed any problems. Actually, it has several algorithms to maximise throughput, and you can get quite amazing results (I got >90 MB/s on a 100 MB/s Ethernet LAN). It works fine over slow / high latency links, too.

It's not perfect, of course, and some errors scenarios are not handled the way I'd like, but, for the most part, you just "plug it in" and you're good.

Comment: Thanks! (I'm the OP). This project never went anywhere for me, but it's good to have the info for the future.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want [SCTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol).

Comment: I knew the was a FLA for this but all I could dredge up was RTSP. Missed by one letter. Looks like they have an OS X kernel extension.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I work for a company which produces commercial UDP data transport tools.*

There are a lot of UDP data transport tools out there, including both freeware and commercial software.  Which one you choose will depend on several factors in addition to the ones you already cited:

- What sort of data are you transporting?  Files, program generated streams of data, short messages?  Kilobytes, megabytes, gigabytes, or terabytes?  Most of the UDP solutions out there are focused on files or large data streams.  Few are also optimized for small or general purpose messaging.
- What is your network topology?  Client-server, peer-to-peer, server-to-server?  This will affect firewall issues, and may affect the cost of commercial solutions.
- What sort of network environment do you expect to deploy in?  Some UDP based transport protocols are only suited to very fast networks or networks in which end-users are capable of configuring the proper target speed.  Others are optimized for low-speed, high latency (like satellite).  Some work well in any environment.
- How much money are you willing to spend?  There exist both open source and commercial solutions.  Prices amongst the commercial solutions vary dramatically and may depend on some of the factors above.
- How much support do you need?  Some open source solutions have robust communities around them, some are nearly abandoned.  Likewise, the level of support amongst the commercial solutions varies.

Obviously I'm trying to walk a fine line to give you things to consider without promoting my own company.  My apologies to all if I've stepped too far to either side.

Comment: Could you name some opensource alternatives for small messages, Client-Server based for an online game where precision is not super important (only about 3 position updates per second, most messages are less than 20bytes)

Comment: For that sort of case you really don't need flow control or error recovery: just send the datagrams.  The important thing is to make sure that your positions are absolute (not relative) so that the loss of any one message is harmless.  You do need ordering, so send a serial number in each packet, record the highest number at the receiver, and ignore any packet with a smaller number.

Comment: You misunderstood me - it also sents other messages which are important (damage calculated by server etc) the positons is just one example that are sent all the itme

Comment: I have not used it, but you could try something like the [Open Game Protocol](http://www.open-game-protocol.org).  That may be overkill.  Consider whether you can make each message stand-alone (current health instead of damage done), rather than have to suffer lag from recovering lost packets.  If the total stats are too big to fit in one datagram, break some of them up: only include some stats every other message, for example.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/udp-vs-tcp/) tutorial series might be of your interest.

**Edit:** The links for the next tutorial is on the bottom of the page, and the post of the Reliable UDP is actually the 3rd one, but the first and the second are good readings also.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [RTI-DDS](http://www.rti.com/products/dds/index.html). There's a C++ API and a QoS that guarantees delivery over UDP. Not sure about Mac support, but you can ask them at support@rti.com.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking for something like [RUDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliable_User_Datagram_Protocol).

In any case, it's hugely complicated to implement. I don't know of anything that does

I also wanted to highlight the fact that if this isn't done in the kernel, the performance drops dramatically. Generally doing things like packet reassembly, etc., in an application either requires a lot more buffering or is going to generate a lot more retries if the data rates are high enough (which can be a fairly modest amount of traffic.)

Comment: I think that RUDP is implemented by Linux in the Berkley Sockets API, but I'm not sure about Darwin. Do you know?

Comment: No, I don't. As you mentioned, there a number of protocols for these but few general implementations.

Comment: I can also completely avoid running on Mac, and just run a Linux virtual machine on the Mac. I think I'll use RUDP.

Comment: Do you know of *any* documentation on how to use RUDP in the Linux Berkeley Sockets API? I could not find anything.